# firebase authentication in flutter ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_CODE for email link authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I had an email link authentication setup for my flutter app and it was working perfectly in sending an email and registering users.

I just changed my public-facing project name in the firebase console and now users are getting  the error 
ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_CODE. Platform exception action code in the link is malformed, expired, or has already been used. 
Nothing fancy here. this particular piece of code was working flawlessly.

```
            AuthResult result =
                await auth.signInWithEmailAndLink(email: email, link: link);
} catch (error) {
print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was something with the project settings and refresh. It started to work today again.

Comment: Can you please suggest what changes you made to settings, and what refresh you did, i am also facing same issue.

Comment: @LokeshSurage it started to fail again. I have raised an issue with the flutter https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1537

Comment: any solutions you found ? I have a js web. I received email but when click on it it gives me same error.